# what does 1 indicate in sizer.add in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

can anyone help me out in knowing what exactly does -1 indicate in following line of code. And what if I put ant any other number instead of 1?

```
sizer.Add(Splitter, 1, wx.EXPAND)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the `proportion` parameter.
The proportion defines how large the sizer’s children are in relation to each other.

`Add(window, proportion=0, flag=0, border=0, userData=None)`

> proportion (int) – this parameter is used in a Sizer to indicate if a child of a sizer can change its size in the main orientation of the Sizer - where 0 stands for not changeable and a value of more than zero is interpreted relative to the value of other children of the same Sizer. For example, you might have a horizontal wx.BoxSizer with three children, two of which are supposed to change their size with the sizer. Then the two stretchable windows would get a value of 1 each to make them grow and shrink equally with the sizer’s horizontal dimension.

Thus one could also define an item to be twice as stretchable by giving it a proportion of 2.

Your example strictly should be written as:

```
sizer.Add(Splitter, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND, border=0)
```

However, programmers being habitually lazy, take shortcuts.